# Is it possible to fork a javascript function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, fork

I try to execute a long run function from my main javascript file. I have 2 cpus so how can I just fork a function ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is node.js documentation on forking and child processes in node.

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Looks like you might be able to do something like this.

```
var child = require('child_process').fork('child.js');
child.on("message", function(){});
```

And you would need the child.js file in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For browser-side javascript you would use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers) for such a task, the functionality has been ported to NodeJS here [Design of Web Workers for NodeJS](http://blog.std.in/2010/07/08/nodejs-webworker-design/) which wraps [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) API call with the message passing abilities of Web Workers.